# 401(k) withdrawal process timeline

Tags: united-states, 401k, withdrawal

I have a 401(k) plan from my previous employer with a little over $5k in it and I have decided to withdraw the full amount.

How long should I expect this process take?

The plan administrator is the owner of the company where I was formerly employed and relations were 'a little strained' when I left, so I am concerned that he is (once again) playing games and messing me about...

Comment: how long since you submitted the request?

Comment: Are you retirement age, are you rolling over into an IRA, or are you taking an early withdrawal?

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer 1 month

Comment: @BenMiller Early withdrawal

Answer (score 2):

1 month seems like too long.

Legally, if you request a distribution the process should be completed "as soon as administratively feasible". 1 month seems out of bounds for administratively feasible, but it's a vague terminology anyway.